# Babel Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I`m tryng to use Babel-loader on an old project, and i notice some issues regarding when babel loader is working on wrapped objects, is this its default behaviour ? I am not sure if this is a bug or something im doing wrong, i could not find much about it over google, so this is my last resource.

Would i need to change something to my code to make it work ?

This are my current specs:
 Webpack: 3.19.0
 babel/core: 7.0.0-beta.34
 babel-loader: 8.0.0-beta.0

Please refer to my packages.json if needed:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/26187880/

I`m tryng to load a single file wrapped in a function:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/26187814/

Resuming, something old, that is built like this:

```
(  window.global = { } )();
```

This is my webpack config:

```
const webpackConfig = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: '../../JavaScript/Namespacing.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
          }
        ]
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/../../static/js",
      filename: "[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ],
}
```

And the error i get on my file is the following:

`Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.`

So, am i missing something ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can I see your `.babelrc`?

Comment: @Gabriel Slomka was your problem solved with the answer given below?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I got the same error with `babel 7.x` and and `"babel-loader": "^8.0.4"`

I solved the issue by changing the following dependencies in `package.json.`
[I got the solution from these link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6808#issuecomment-343792786)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
}
```

and in `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
}
```

or in `package.json`

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/react"
    ]
},
```

If you are using `npm` then use the following

```
npm install @babel/core --save-dev
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm install @babel/preset-react --save-dev
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
npm install webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack-cli --save-dev
```

If you are using yarn, then use the following

```
yarn add @babel/core --dev
yarn add @babel/preset-env --dev
yarn add @babel/preset-react --dev
yarn add babel-loader --dev
yarn add webpack --dev
yarn add webpack-cli --dev
```

Comment: In the `.babelrc` file, I believe that should be `"@babel/preset-env"` instead of `"@babel/env"`. Also, an explanation while upgrading to Babel 7 "@babel/preset-env (Transpiles files using ES6, ES7, and ES8. The same as babel-preset-latest, which includes babel-preset-es2015, babel-preset-es2016, and babel-preset-es2017. However, babel-preset-latest is deprecated and replaced by babel-preset-env, so that’s why we’re using babel-preset-env." from: https://medium.com/@jeffrey.allen.lewis/the-ultimate-2018-webpack-4-and-babel-setup-guide-npm-yarn-dependencies-compared-entry-points-866b577da6a

Answer (score 11):

From your package.json, I can see that you are using older plugins and presets meant for Babel v6, which will result in this error message.  You need to switch to e.g., `@babel/preset-env`, then update your `.babelrc` accordingly (if you provide `.babelrc`, more specific guidance can be given).

Here is a related ticket with some explanation - https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/540

A few more semi-related notes on what I see in `package.json`:

The old `babel-core` dependency is still there.  Remove this or update it to version `7.0.0-bridge.0`.  Similarly, the old react preset is in there, remove it.

If you are using the `env` preset, you do not need to use the `es2015` preset at all.  Remove it.

Answer (score 6):

### Babel has been moved its packages into its **Scope Repository** Since **version 7.x** .

---

the last version of babel packages (in **main npmjs** ) are :

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
...
```

but you have to use **The Continued** version in **@babel/** scoped repository:

by today these are :

```
"@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.16",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
...
```

so you have to uninstall and install them:

```
npm uninstall babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react
npm install @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

or :

```
yarn remove babel-core babel-preset-env babel-preset-react --dev
yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react --dev
```

> Note 1: you can add a `@` and change first `-` to `/`
>
> Note 2: note that, The **babel-loader** package is not in babel
> package, its a module for **webpack** to load babel. (it remains
> bebel-loader with latest version)

---

after changing babel to its scope you have to make required changes in the `.babelrc` :

from:

```
"presets" : ["env","react"]
```

to :

```
"presets" : ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
```

Answer (score 1):

answers are for old versions. currently this set up is enough:

```
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
```

if you are using this package "babel-preset-stage-0" on top of those you will still get same error. So uninstall "babel-preset-stage-0" and make sure your all babel packages are starts with "@babel" except "babel-loader". @babel indicates that the package is maintained by the babel team

Answer (score 1):

Most of the packages were not even installed. So, this is the combination which actually worked. Remember to delete your node_modules before testing and changes in .babelrc is important. Updated devDependencies of package.json and .babelrc from.

**Updated from:**

```
1. Package.json file:

"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
}


2. .babelrc file:

{
   "presets": [
      "env",
      "react",
      "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

**Updated to:**

```
1. Package.json file:

"devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
      "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
      "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
      "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
      "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
      "webpack": "^4.46.0"
}


2. .babelrc file:

{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/react"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-react-jsx"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***this worked for me:***

npm uninstall --save babel-loader

npm uninstall --save @babel/core

npm install --save-dev babel-loader@^7

***and in babelrc:***

"presets" : ["env", "react"]