# Error running webpack with react-grid-layout: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-grid-layout

I'm trying to use [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) in a .NET core MVC application. I've set up node.js and react using [this guide](https://codeburst.io/how-to-use-webpack-in-asp-net-core-projects-a-basic-react-template-sample-25a3681a5fc2), which works just fine. Now I'm trying to include a react-grid-layout component, but I get errors while running webpack. First it demanded to have the babel preset `es2015` installed, even though I'm already using `@babel/preset-env`. After installing `es2015` the error changed to:

```
Module build failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

Searching for other people having this issue I only found posts, where the solution was to use the babel presets `@babel/preset-react` and `@babel/preset-env`, which I already do. Here is what I found so far:

- [Babel Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47830273/babel-plugin-preset-files-are-not-allowed-to-export-objects-only-functions)
- https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6808
- https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/575

My `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('allstyles.css')

module.exports = {
    entry: {'main': './wwwroot/src/app.js'},
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract(['css-loader? minimize'])
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-react' ,'@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }

            }]
    }
};
```

And my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "ASPNetCoreReact",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "wbp": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.40",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

I've also pushed an [example project to github](https://github.com/species-gh/Babel_RGL_Issue) where the error can be reproduced.

Any ideas where the error might come from? Maybe I just set up something wrong? I'm totally new to .net core, node and react, so that is quite probable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution myself. As suggested in [this issue at github](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/556) I downgraded `babel-loader 8.0.0-beta`, `@babel/core`, `@babel/preset-env` and `@babel/preset-react` to `babel-loader 7.1.4`, `babel-core`, `babel-preset-env` and `babel-preset-react`. Additionally I had to upgrade `es2015` to `env` in the `.babelrc` of `react-grid-layout` and `react-resizeable` as suggested in [this pull request.](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/pull/725/files)